# Pass Data Between Two View Controllers When Using a Tab Controller Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, viewcontroller

I am building a simple app that has two tabs. A "White Noise" tab and a "Log" tab. When a white noise sound is played or stopped, I log this data to show the date and time when a sound was played or stopped. My only issue is that I cannot figure out how to pass the `log` array when I click on the "Log" tab. I have tried using the following code in my "White Noise" tab:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var logView = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    logView.log.append("Testing 123")
}
```

But I have come to realize that with a Tab Bar Controller, the transition from one View Controller to another is not technically a `segue`. So my question is how do I pass data between View Controllers using a Tab Bar Controller?

**Update**

I have created a new class called `CustomTabBarControllerClass`. Here is my code for this class:

```
class CustomTabBarControllerClass: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        println("Test 123!")
    }

}
```

I have set the `CustomTabBarControllerClass` as the "custom class" in Interface Builder. However, the `println("Test 123!")` still is not displaying in the console when I am switching tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` has a delegate, which has a method 
`tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` you can use that to accomplish what you're looking for.

Apple's documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)

Comment: Thank you for this info. I added the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to my "White Noise" View Controller class. I then implemented the function you mentioned. I then added the following code to the function: `println("Switching tabs")`. However, this still did not work for me. Nothing was printed to the console. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: You want to set the delegate of the UITabBarController and not the contained ViewControllers. You can do that by creating a class that extends UITabBarController, then set it in the interface builder as the class for the UITabBarController element. In that class overwrite <code>awakeFromNib</code> with something like this:

     - (void) awakeFromNib
     {
          self.delegate = self;
     }

Comment: Put the function that prints "switching tabs" into that new class.

Comment: Bert, thanks for the help so far. I believe I have done what you suggested. I have updated my original question with the new code. Please take a look. I feel like we are close to getting this to work. I must be missing something simple at this point.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work! I did not add the awakeFromNib code to my custom class. Thank you very much for all of your help!